# getting the title of a child of an element

Tags: javascript

I have a JavaScript file that prints the `title` attribute of the child `img` element inside of it.

In other words, I have an `img` tag inside an `a` tag. The `img` tag has a `title` attribute inside of it. I want to get that attribute.

Here is my JavaScript code. The `el` variable is the a element which contains the `img` element.

```
c.innerHTML += x + y + "<h1>" + el.childNodes[0].title +"</h1>" + z;
```

For some reason, however, the `el.childNodes[0].title` doesn't work. It just returns the following value:

```
undefined
```

I've tried using `el.firstChild.title` as well, but it still returns the same value.

Here is my HTML code:

```
<a class="nanobox-img" href="index.html" rel="nanobox-single-override">
    <img src="../../images/testnull.gif" title="This is a NanoBox Demo"/>
</a>
```

Comment: Since you have no text content in the <a> element, so it will only display the image, why not give the link the title?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of `childNodes`, use `children`.

```
el.children[0].title
```

This is because most browsers will consider white space between nodes *(line breaks, tabs, etc.)* to be a DOM text node, so the first node is likely the that text node.

---

You could also do this...

```
el.firstElementChild.title
```

...though I think `.children` has a little broader support.

Answer (score 2):

With [jQuery](http://jquery.com/) this is quite simple:

```
$("a.nanabox-big img").attr("title");
```

---

Or as a click event:

```
$(function(){
    $("a.nanobox-img").click(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        alert($(this).find("img").attr("title"));            
    });        
});​
```

http://jsfiddle.net/UNfsp/1/

Comment: I don't see any indication that OP is using jQuery.

Comment: @amnotiam There is no indication, but that doesn't mean it can't be suggested.

Comment: He might start doing so though. And while jQuery is really not necessary for such a simple thing if there are almost no DOM operations on the page anyway, it starts to become extremely useful if you start using more JavaScript on your pages...

Comment: @ThiefMaster, Curt: Then that makes it comment-worthy perhaps, but not directly relevant unless OP has indicated a desire or ability to use a 3rd party library.

Comment: It does answer the question though. He did not mention that he cannot/does not want to use a library.

Comment: @ThiefMaster: It only answers the question if jQuery is being used. By your rationale, *every* JavaScript question would need to have a statement indicating that jQuery, and perhaps every other library, is not being used. Does that seem like a reasonable expectation to you? It would mean that any question without that disclaimer could receive answers from any and all various JavaScript libraries. That would make actual JavaScript questions a complete mess, and much less useful.